# It is supposed to increment wherever it finds a similar entry

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
for(var i= 0; i < foundRecords.length ; i++){
  var MaleChildNew=0,
      MaleNew=0, 
      femaleChildNew=0, 
      femaleNew=0, 
      policeMaleChildNew = 0, 
      policefemaleChildNew=0, 
      policeMaleNew=0, 
      policefemaleNew=0, 
      npoliceMaleChildNew=0, 
      npoliceMaleNew=0, 
      npolicefemaleChildNew=0, 
      npolicefemaleNew=0;
      if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policeMaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policefemaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policeMaleNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policefemaleNew++;
      } if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    npoliceMaleChildNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    npolicefemaleChildNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    npoliceMaleNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    npolicefemaleNew++;
                } if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    MaleChildNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    femaleChildNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    MaleNew++;
                }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    femaleNew++;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that it only increments the category which it finds in the end of the database and returns 1 for the same. What I want is that it should increment the value for every entry it finds similar and save the value. But this code returns 0 for all other variables and 1 for the one which is at the end of the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will always initialise the variables to 0 as they are inside the `for` loop. So, the variables are reset to 0 for each item of `foundRecords`. Thus, declare your variables outside the `for` loop:

```
var MaleChildNew=0,
    MaleNew=0, 
    femaleChildNew=0, 
    femaleNew=0, 
    policeMaleChildNew = 0, 
    policefemaleChildNew=0, 
    policeMaleNew=0, 
    policefemaleNew=0, 
    npoliceMaleChildNew=0, 
    npoliceMaleNew=0, 
    npolicefemaleChildNew=0, 
    npolicefemaleNew=0;

for(var i= 0; i < foundRecords.length ; i++){
      if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policeMaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policefemaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policeMaleNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
      policefemaleNew++;
      } if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
                    npoliceMaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          npolicefemaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          npoliceMaleNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          npolicefemaleNew++;
      } if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          MaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] <= 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          femaleChildNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'male' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          MaleNew++;
      }else if(foundRecords[i]['age'] > 12 && foundRecords[i]['patientType'] == 'policePerson' && foundRecords[i]['sex'] == 'female' && foundRecords[i]['opdType'] == 'new' ){
          femaleNew++;
      }
}
```

Comment: never considered that small detail :P
Thanks

Comment: You can tick mark it green, if it was really helpful to you. Glad to help you.